# React Native SectionList scrollToLocation not working inside a scrollview

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to have a normal info view and a sectionList inside a scrollView. Though the view gets scrolled, when I try to use **scrollToLocation** for scrolling to specific index selected it is not scrolling. Also I have tried using other props **onMomentumScrollEnd** in sectionList which is also not working. When I remove scrollView it works perfectly.

```
<ScrollView>
                    <View style={{ height: 300, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)' }} />
                    <View>
                        <SectionList
                            ref={(ref) => (this.contentRef = ref)}
                            stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
                            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                            sections={sectionListData}
                            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                            onMomentumScrollEnd={() => {
                                this.setState({ onScrollFinished: true });
                                this.setViewableItem();
                            }}
                            onScrollEndDrag={() => {
                                this.setViewableItem();
                            }}
                            onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
                            renderItem={this.renderSectionItem}
                            renderSectionHeader={!this.props.isMenuLoading && this.renderSectionHeader}
                            initialNumToRender={500}
                            onScrollToIndexFailed={(info) => console.log('info', info)}
                        />
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
```

```
setActiveIndex(key) {
        this.setState({ activeIndex: key, updatedAt: Date.now() });
        if (isValidElement(this.headerRef)) {
            this.headerRef.scrollToIndex({ index: key, animated: true, viewPosition: 0.5 });
        }
        if (isValidElement(this.contentRef)) {
            this.contentRef.scrollToLocation({
                sectionIndex: key,
                itemIndex: 0,
                animated: false,
                viewPosition: 0
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is a long-standing issue which no one seems to have an answer for. [Issue #25295](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25295) on the react-native repository from June 2019 reported this behavior and was automatically closed as stale after 3 months. [Issue #31136](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31136) reports the same problem, and there are presumably other references to it as well.

The behavior appears to be related to the underlying implementation of the `scroll*` imperative functions. Specifically, the call stack looks something like this:

- `scrollToIndex` in `VirtualizedList`
- `scrollToLocation` in `VirtualizedSectionList`
- `scrollToLocation` in `SectionList`

The bit that fails is when `VirtualizedList` attempts to call `this._scrollRef.scrollTo`, which is apparently not defined when the `SectionList` is nested in a `ScrollView` or other scrollable component like `FlatList`.

My suggestion would be to refactor the layout such that there are not scrollable items nested under other scrollable items on the same axis.